# How to normalize indentations but not line-breaks when serialising / reading XML in C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, line-breaks, code-formatting

I have an XML document, which I want to serialize with normalized indentations (using two spaces), but preserving any additional line-breaks between Elements. I am using C#. Preferably I would normalize the line-break *characters* (so they are all `\r\n`), but crucially I would like to keep the presence of multiple consecutive line-breaks.

For example, given the input document:

```xml
<root>
    <elementOne>Hello</elementOne>
  <elementTwo>I am misaligned</elementTwo>
        <elementThree>I am indented with a Tab character</elementThree>

    <!-- Here is a comment preceeding another element -->
    <elementFour />
  </root>
```

I would like to produce the output document:

```xml
<root>
    <elementOne>Hello</elementOne>
    <elementTwo>I am slightly misaligned</elementTwo>
    <elementThree>I am indented with a Tab character</elementThree>

    <!-- Here is a comment preceeding another element -->
    <elementFour />
</root>
```

If I parse the input document to an `XElement` and then serialise it, I get the output with normalized spacing, but the extra line-break removed:

```xml
<root>
    <elementOne>Hello</elementOne>
    <elementTwo>I am slightly misaligned</elementTwo>
    <elementThree>I am indented with a Tab character</elementThree>
    <!-- Here is a comment preceeding another element -->
    <elementFour />
</root>
```

I have tried using `XDocument.Load` with `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace`, but then I cannot find a way to get indentation normalization. I have also tried using `XmlWriterSettings` as follows:

```cs
XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings {
    Indent = true,
    IndentChars = "  ",
    NewLineChars = "\r\n",
    NewLineHandling = NewLineHandling.None
};
```

But tweaking these settings seems to either normalize both line-breaks *and* indentation, or neither.

The reason I want this behavior is that I want to "pretty-print" a large user-editable XML document so that the indentation is correct, but I don't want to remove the line-breaks added by the user for readability.

Comment: The ident = true should ident the xml output so it is indented properly.  What may be causing issues is the innertext having extra spaces and returns.  So maybe you want to trim() all the innertext.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to preserve only parts of the whitespace between elements: either the whitespace is considered significant or it isn't.

A different solution is to replace all the blank lines with a placeholder comment, format the document in the usual way, and then remove the comments (but leaving the empty lines).

For example:

```
public static class XmlFormatting {

    static readonly string sNewLineComment = new XComment($"x-newline-placeholder-{Guid.NewGuid()}").ToString();
    static readonly Regex sNewLineCommentRegex = new Regex($@"^\s*{sNewLineComment}\s*$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
    static readonly Regex sEmptyLineRegex = new Regex(@"^\s*$", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);

    public static string PrettyPrintXml(string inputXml) {
        string newlinesReplacedWithComments = sEmptyLineRegex.Replace(inputXml, sNewLineComment);
        string formattedDocument = XDocument.Parse(newlinesReplacedWithComments, LoadOptions.None).ToString();
        return sNewLineCommentRegex.Replace(formattedDocument, string.Empty);
    }
}
```